# my Ec2 instance is not accessible behind a load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

in my AWS I used to have an instance-A.

Instance-A was on VPC-1 and SUbnet-1. It was also behind a loadBalancer-X.

loadBalancer-X    has DNS name --> dualstack.abc-lb-123.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.

from AWS Route 53 - you can see hosted zones

RecordName:  abcRecord.com
value/route Traffic to  --> dualstack.abc-lb-123.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

---

Now

In Instance-A (windows) I had a python flask application running  listening at port 5000.  From outside say my local PC I could access --> https://abcRecord.com:5000/xyz (xyz is the entry for a POST or GET method for flask on port 5000)
all was good

Two days ago I no longer could remote desk top to instance-A, I rebooted it, stopped and started it many times no luck.

I finally decided to recreate a new instance B with all SW which was on A in same exact VPC and subnet. I also registered this new instance B on that same loadBalancer-X , you can go to Registered Targets and see the new instance-B. I stopped instance-A.

In Instance B I ran my application which is listening on port 5000.    Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Within remote desktop of instance B I can open a browser go to say  --> http://localhost:5000/xyz  where xyz is the entry for a POST or GET

The thing is from outside AWS  say my laptop I am not able to access https://abcRecord.com

Comment: Are you sure that the instance B has the same security groups as the A had?

Comment: They have different security groups. What should do I do, should I make them the same? Sorry I am not expert in AWS

Comment: First, test the ability to go directly to the instance (assuming that it is in a public subnet). You would access `http://1.2.3.4:5000` (using the public IP address of the instance). If that is working, then add it to the Target Group for the load balancer and try sending traffic that way. If you are using an Application Load Balancer, then the security group on the instance will need to permit inbound traffic from the Load Balancer's security group.

Comment: Thanks so much it is fixed.  I had two problems A) as you said I added the security group of my instance-B to the load balancer targets, B) My problem all along was that the  public IP address of my PC has changed so I should have added that to the security group